# Analytics on local HTML5 web app?

Tags: networking, web-applications, network-programming

I'm building a HTML 5 web-app being delivered from local web server (being created by [mamp](http://www.mamp.info/)) over a wireless network with no access to the internet.

I'm wondering if there's a solution for tracking Analytics for the web-app without it being connected to the internet.

I'm not super knowledgable about networks, so any info helps.

Comment: When you say analytics do you mean Google Analytics or any analytics software? Google analytics shouldn't be a problem as long as it can connect to the google servers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could install something like http://piwik.org/ on one of the machines on your network.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can track analytics as long as the browser viewing the site has access to the Internet and not just a LAN.